# What is an auxillary winding in a flyback transformer?

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I am researching about SMPS, specifically AC/DC flyback converters.

In the datasheet for the switching controller (Fairchild FSCQ0765), it refers to an auxiliary winding. What is that? All the current transformers I've looked at only have a primary and secondary winding.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The auxiliary winding is the one that is not a primary or secondary.

In this case it provides power and a timing signal (synchronization) to the controller- since it's a quasi-resonant controller it needs to be in tune with the transformer.

Comment: What kind of transformer provides an auxiliary winding? I have looked at isolation transformers, as well as high frequency current transformers, and both these only have a primary and secondary coil.

Comment: Usually these are custom transformers, not off-the-shelf, unless someone happens to offer a transformer for this particular chip.

Comment: Most of the flyback controllers I've looked at have some sort of auxiliary winding. Does this mean homebrew SMPS's are almost impossible to make?

Comment: You can wind your own transformer. The number of turns is usually reasonable, and you can fake the gapping with a spacer at the cost of a bit more EMI. Small quantities are more of a problem than one-offs IME.

Comment: @tgun926  [Here's a thread, which deals with finding transformers for SMPS.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/71852/7036)  In general, it's safe to assume that off-the-shelf transformers for SMPS are... scarce.