# Derive Parameters for Unknown Flyback Transformer

Tags: transformer, flyback

I am designing a 1.7 kV @ 6 mA flyback power supply. The issue I have is that it seems to be extremely difficult to find any type of high voltage flyback transformers for the design. I bought a cheap generic CRT flyback to experiment with, but being generic it has no datasheet to speak of. I assume I can derive the winding ratio easily enough, but what about the other parameters? For example, to figure out the optimum frequency can I just do a frequency sweep until I find the highest output voltage?

Comment: The part where you ask how to characterize a transformer is very much on-topic.  The second part of the question where you ask for a place where you would buy the transformer is off-topic.  I took a liberty to edit that away.

Comment: Also [this related thread](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/71845/7036).

Comment: Yeah, I figured that might be the case, thank you for the edit. I'll checkout the other topic too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the core saturation and permeability you probably need a function generator with the ability to generate a high enough voltage/power.

I am not sure what the primary looks like in your case but I am thinking  of an audio amp or maybe the type of amplifiers EMC people use in there test. The latter are expensive and not easy to come by for the average hobbyist.

Use an oscilloscope to measure the current over a series resistance to determine the impedance and saturation point at different frequencies. Then work you way back through the typical solenoid formulas do determine the core properties.